# How can I auto-reply with skype only to certain messages?

Tags: windows-7, skype, skype-for-business

Commonly at work I return from being away to a rather useful message on Skype:

```
hi
```

Once such a greeting is returned the individual will continue with what they're actually looking for, but until then they wont tell me their concern. This means waiting for me to return from being away, and then possibly waiting for them returning from being away before I can actually hear what they were looking for.

I was wondering that I could set an auto-reply only to specific messages, such as 'hi' 'hello' 'hey' etc. If a message exactly matches one of these send an auto-reply (which would probably just be 'hello') so they'll continue on with their request/concern/etc which I can discover upon returning to my desk or even if I just don't notice their message.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to deliver bad news but you can't, unless your *Recipient* gets put on a favorite list (i.e., contacts you a ton).

Comment: What is the possibilities with the favorite list? People can be pinned to favorites, I wouldn't mind doing that specifically to people I encounter who require greetings

Comment: the favorite list is hear. you dont have to pin them its on there automatically when you talk to them alot

Comment: Your answer suggests that an auto-reply is possible if they are in the favorites list though, how is this done?